# JSON to powershell

Tags: json, powershell

**Guys, I have been told:
"In your POST body you’re not passing friends as an array,"
Actual JSON: once I have this JSON into powershell format, I am planning invoke a get request as below.

```
{"friends":[{"friendId":"abc1234-456Yes-repeat"}],"wowMorefriends":{"morefriendsId":{"hmmmMoreFriendsId":"09876tyuhtre-repeated"}},"callMe":0,"param":{}}
```

PowershellCode:

```
$Data = @{

    friends = @{"friendId" = "abc1234-456Yes-repeat"}

    wowMorefriends = @(

            @{

"morefriendsId" = @{"hmmmMoreFriendsId" = "09876tyuhtre-repeated"}

            "callMe" = 0

            "param" = {}

            }

        )

    }

   

 

$JsData = $Data | ConvertTo-Json -Compress



$JsData





Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "https://App1.Callingmyfriends.com/api/callactions/run" -Body $JsData -ContentType 'application/json' -WebSession $cookieSession -Headers $requestHeaders -UseBasicParsing
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `friends` should be an array of objects, you'd want to set it the same way you set `wowMoreFriends`, in `@()`. Also you need to set param to `@{}`, not `{}` otherwise you will have issues depending on the version of Powershell you are using.

```bsh
$Data = @{
    friends = @(
        @{
            "friendId" = "abc1234-456Yes-repeat"
         }
    )
    wowMorefriends = @(
        @{
            "morefriendsId" = @{"hmmmMoreFriendsId" = "09876tyuhtre-repeated"}
            "callMe" = 0
            "param" = @{}
         }
     )
}
```

But in addition to that, `morefriendsId` has exceeded `ConvertTo-Json`'s default max depth. So you will also need to set a larger depth via `-Depth`, for instance:

```
$JsData = $Data | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 4
```